# Read problems using getw()

Tags: c

so I'm working on this program that read from a text file which is filled with non prime and prime numbers, so it first reads all the numbers from one text file and then it outputs only the prime numbers to another text file.

Let say one text file has:

```
233
179
178
199
198
157
```

On the second it should print or copy:

```
233
179
199
157
```

So far I have worked on the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *in_file;
    int numbers;

    in_file = fopen("file1.txt", "r");

    while ( fscanf(in_file, "%d", &numbers) == 1) {
            printf("%d\n", numbers);
        }
        fclose(in_file);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem with the above code is that the reads are wrong, the output to the screen is not the same as in file1, and I'm not sure whether is to do with the getw() function or somewhere else in the code?

Comment: What's the output you get?

Comment: Are you sure `getw` is the right function to use? Your example data doesn't look like a binary file

Comment: `getw` reads a word (int) and printf converts it to string representing the number `od -An -tu4 < file1.txt` should give similar output, also this dump command `od -c -x -tu4 <file1.txt` may help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `int getw(FILE *)` function is for reading an integer directly from the bytes of a file, not for reading an integer from the textual contents of a file.

If you wish to read integers from a file, one by one, use `fscanf` instead:

```
FILE *in_file = fopen("file1.txt", "r");
FILE *out_file = fopen("file2.txt", "w");
int num;
while (fscanf(in_file, "%d", &num) == 1) {
    if (is_prime(num)) {
        fprintf(out_file, "%d\n", num);
    }
}
fclose(in_file);
fclose(out_file);
```

Comment: Yh that works now, i had it commented as well but i didnt know you needed "==1", in order now to move the prime numbers to another text file i should include the code below this while statements right?

Comment: @Maria Inside the `while` loop, you check if the integer is prime and then you write it to the file with `fprintf(out_file, "%d\n", num)` (I will edit my answer with this).